# array of hashes example fails

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

I have a problem with multi dimension arrays. I then tried a sample in the book *Perl 4th edition*, page 379, and that failed as well! Why?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# example in manual page 379
# input from file containing: husband=fred pal=barney wife=wilma     pet=dino
while ( <> ) {
 next unless s/^(.*?):\s*//;
 my $who = $1;
  for my $field ( split ) {
  (my $key, my $value) = split /=/, $field;
  my $HoH{$who}{$key} = $value;
 }
}
```

`

Answer (score 2):

Useful trick for illustrative examples - you can in line `__DATA__` at the end of your file, and use that.

Anyway, when I run your code, I get:

```
Global symbol "$key" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $key"?)
Global symbol "$value" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $value"?
```

You are also declaring `%HoH` badly - you shouldn't use that form, and instead:

```
my %HoH;
```

And *also* that regex - will skip your input text, because it's looking for `:` and your input doesn't contain any. I will assume that like should be prefixed with `flintstone:`.

So to simplify and give you something that works:

```
#! usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %HoH;

while (<DATA>) {
   next unless s/^(.*?):\s*//;
   my $who = $1;
   for my $field (split) {
      my ( $key, $value ) = split /=/, $field;
      $HoH{$who}{$key} = $value;
   }
}

print Dumper \%HoH;

__DATA__
flintstone: husband=fred pal=barney wife=wilma pet=dino
```

This outputs the dumped HoH:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'flintstone' => {
                       'husband' => 'fred',
                       'wife' => 'wilma',
                       'pal' => 'barney',
                       'pet' => 'dino'
                     }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains some syntax errors, and your input text is wrong (there is no `:`

Try this:

```
my %HoH;
while ( <DATA> ) {
    next unless s/^(.*?):\s*//;
    my $who = $1;
    for my $field ( split ) {
            my ($key, $value) = split /=/, $field;
            $HoH{$who}{$key} = $value;
        }
    }

print Dumper \%HoH;

__DATA__
flintstones: husband=fred pal=barney wife=wilma pet=dino
```